# Delay Auto Run .sh Files At Start

Tags: noobs

I have been working on having my raspberry pi display a slideshow. I have the images that are needed to display located on a personal cloud (a WD MyCloud).
I have made a .sh file called "startup.sh" located at "/home/pi" that will connect to the cloud, and start the slideshow.
I wish to make this automatic, but all the tutorials on automatic doing this process is at bootup, which won't work because it's not connected to the cloud yet. So I wish to a delay that can allow the pi to start up fully before running the startup.sh.
Any ideas how you can help?

Answer (score 1):

To delay for a fixed number of seconds, just use the `sleep` command. For 30 seconds, use

```
sleep 30
```

If you want to delay until the network is reachable, you can use

```
while ! ping -w 1 8.8.8.8 &> /dev/null; do true; done
```

This will try to ping 8.8.8.8, Google's nameserver, and exit the loop as soon as the ping is successful.

Comment: Okay sweet, now knowing that, where would you recommend putting that?

Comment: Before the other commands that start your slideshow.

Comment: What would be your suggestion to start this .sh file at startup?

Comment: @user46629 You can edit your question. Please complete it with all what you want to know instead of asking step by step in comments.